# For what prime numbers $p$ is $17p + 1$ a perfect square?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

For what prime numbers $p$ is $17p + 1$ a perfect square?

All I have so far is

$17p+1 = x^2$ and now I'm stuck

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$17p+1=n^2\iff 17p=n^2-1=(n+1)(n-1)$ Therefore $n+1$ or $n-1$ is $17$.

Comment: What theorem allows you to conclude that if $n^2-1=17p$ then $n-1$ or $n+1$ is $17$. It seems to me that you have used the fact that each number has a unique prime factorization. But how can one rule out the possibility of both $n+1$ and $n-1$ being composite numbers?

Comment: Notice that $17p$ is the product of exactly two primes.